# Hibernate ObjectDeletedException ManyToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have an entity with a many-to-one relationship (One Usuario/ Many Gestionar) and Gestionar entity has another ManyToOne inside...It's the way I'm doing the ManyToMany relationship.I do not know how to delete Gestionar and not eliminate the entity Incidencia.

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [gestionDeIncidencias.persistencia.Gestionar#1]
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.forceFlush(SessionImpl.java:1139)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:182)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:641)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:633)
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:259)
> at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:380)
> at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323)
> at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
> at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:409)
> at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:350)
> at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:326)
> at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
> at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:160)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:151)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:88)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1127)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:325)
> at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
> at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
> at gestionDeIncidencias.dao.GenericDAO.borrar(GenericDAO.java:48)
> at gestionDeIncidencias.modelo.Principal.borrarUsuarioPorDni(Principal.java:348)
> at gestionDeIncidencias.modelo.Principal.tratarSubmenuUsuario(Principal.java:127)
> at gestionDeIncidencias.modelo.Principal.tratarMenuPrincipal(Principal.java:75)
> at gestionDeIncidencias.modelo.Principal.main(Principal.java:37)

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with many to many, you can acquire the id of the related entity to delete the other related, all this building a hquery:

```
createQuery("DELETE FROM entidad where papa=:father").setParameter("father", fatherId); // This is for delete the child's or related entities to another.
```

"fatherId" should be the id of one entity related to the ones that you want to delete.

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm) you can find the official tutorials of how to create hql queries.

I hope I expressed myself well.

Comment: What would be parent in the syntax if I'm dealing with a list?

Comment: A related entity, lets use 2 of your example entities:if many Gestionar are related to many Incidencias, and you want to delete a Gestionar, "parent" (of my example) can be a Incidencia related to that Gestionar.